# How to write console statement in hyperledger composer

Tags: node.js, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have the transaction code in Hyperledger composer.
How to print all the console statements when the transaction called from the nodejs application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Runtime Log:**

If you run `docker ps -a` you should see basic running docker containers. One of the docker containers will be a chaincode container (your running business network). You will see a particular container id of container.

Then look forward using `docker logs <container id>` you will see your `console.log()` information in your terminal. You can follow the logs using `docker logs -f`

**Developer Log:**

you can see the output in the Developer console. In Firefox and Chrome browsers for example - hit `CTRL-SHIFT-I` and it pops up - then goes to Console and you can see what your **console log** information.

Hope it will help you :)